# ConcurrentModificationException when more then one users is operating on HashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` which stores ID and Name pair.  For each entry of this map, conditionally, I am going to put it in another `HashMap`. At the end am going to do some operations with the second Map Entries. All this code is written in JSP file.

For single user request this is working fine.  When more than one users are trying to access this file at a time, only one request is getting succeeded and resulting the same on other users.

We can see the following exception in the logs:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

Map is in this format

```
Map<String, String> testmap= new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

From the java doc of [java.util.HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

As already suggested, the simplest solution for you is to synchronize the access to the `Map` that is concurrently iterated/modified.

```
Map map = ... //the map object has to be the same for all users calling your jsp

synchronized(map) {
   //do work
}
```

**See also** [oracle java tutorial about concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: What will be the solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

If your map is going to be accessed and modified by many threads at the same time, try to use a better map implementation for your problem: the [ConcurrentHashMap collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) could do the trick for you.

```
final Map<String,String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
```

If you cannot use Java 5:

```
final Map map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
```

Comment: @Gray Thanks for adding some style to my answer. I am a newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

Different requests are probably run on different threads then. You'll have to synchronize on the common datastructure testmap.

There are several ways to achieve this. @Tudor suggests Locks. That would be one possible way. If this is an exercise, I'd recommend to read something about synchronization in multithreading in general and `synchronized` methods in Java.

Comment: does "concurrenthashmap" help for this problem .

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your complete code. I'd say it is a good step into the right direction. But since you iterate over the resource, you will need more than synchronize each call to a method of the resource. You'll need to synchronize the complete iteration, which implies some kind of locking. Either by a `synchronize` block or explicit Lock (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error if you modify the collection while iterating over it, whether this happens from the same thread or from multiple threads concurrently. My suspicion is that it's the second case, since it happens with multiple user requests. Make sure to protect the accesses with locks (perhaps one lock per map object).

Comment: Thanks for responding to my post, how to protect the access with locks, could you give me some info.

Comment: @user1659994: Basically wherever you have a for loop iterating over the map or an add/remove wrap it into a `synchronized` block. Make sure all threads see the same lock object.